# debugging android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I cant find an option to add an alert sound to a breakpoint in eclipse for android although I think I've read that it can be done with C++.   If it is not included in the standard eclipse installation I am wondering if there is an add on to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've certainly never HEARD of any "sounds" for Eclipse...

... and frankly, I'd find it ANNOYING if there were ...

... but check this out:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/199209/

http://negrej.free.fr/foghorn/index.html

'Hope that helps